# How to parse <br> in a string to html tag in VUE.js

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2

I use {{}} in Vue.js to render my data to HTML. But now I got a string in my data, and I want the 
 tags in that string can be parsed into HTML tags when rendering data.

```
data(){
  return {
    bodyText: 'aaaaaa<br>aaaaaa'
}
}
```

```
<p>{{bodyText}}</p>
```

I want the content in span tag is like :

```
aaaaaa
aaaaaa
```

But the result is :
`aaaaaa<br>aaaaaa`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think it should work using [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

```
<p>Using v-html directive: <span v-html="rawHtml"></span></p>
```

Comment: If you are using eslint in your project you may lead to a warning while using v-html.

'v-html' directive can lead to XSS attack  vue/no-v-html

to avoid this you can use it as follows-

<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html -->
<div v-html="bodyText"></div>
<!--eslint-enable-->

Comment: I wonder about the security implications of this, seems like a valid warning to me.

Comment: of course, in this case you have to make sure that no malicious code can be inserted. But there are definitely use-cases where rawHTML is the right way.

Answer (score 18):

Use [`v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

```
<p><span v-html="bodyText"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it still simple by using inside the p tag itself

```
<p v-html="bodyText"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

My example
html

```
<td>
    <span v-html="getInfo(item)"></span>
</td>
```

script

```
getInfo: function (item) {
   return "One line<br />Next line"
}
```